# How to factor $4d^2 -16w^2 -4cd+c^2$ ( from Hart William L., Intermediate Algebra, 1948)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, quadratics, factoring

I found this factoring problem in Hart, *Intermediate Algebra*, 1948, page $97$ , ***problem $n° 60$***, ( at Archive.org).

Link :https://archive.org/details/intermediatealge030183mbp/page/n110/mode/1up

I tried to manipulate the formula using: $m^2n^2 = (mn)^2$ and also : $n^2 - m^2 = (m-n) ( m+n)$; I made use of addition's associativity and commutativity in order to exchange the order of the terms;  but it led nowhere.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It *is* a difference of squares, look more closely.

Comment: @dxiv. - I've got it, finally, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $4d^2-4dc + c^2 = (2d-c)^2$